# VBA Remove Formatting at End of Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some code that loads in data from a file and places it in a excel spreadsheet. I have the code set up so that all the cells in the table have thin, black borders around them. However, after the end of the table there are still borders around all of the cells in the rows below the table. is there any way to make it so after the table ends all of this formatting is undone and the cells just no longer have borders? The table size will be different depending on the file opened in excel.

Comment: If there's a problem with your code, the *show your code*.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first empty cell... then set your range from that cell

```
[insert your range here].Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
[insert your range here].Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```